# Android how to create Observable with varying interval time

Tags: android, rx-java, observable

I want to create an observable that emits every x seconds. This x could be a variable depending on some condition.

Right now I have something which sends me an event ever 4 seconds.

```
Observable.interval(4, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .takeUntil(new Func1<Long, Boolean>() {
      @Override public Boolean call(Long aLong) {
        return !showNextText;
      }
    })
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
    .subscribe(new Action1<Object>() {
      @Override public void call(Object o) {


      }
    }, new Action1<Throwable>() {
      @Override public void call(Throwable throwable) {

      }
    }, new Action0() {
      @Override public void call() {
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `concatMap` and `timer`.

This example will emit after 1 second then emit after 2 seconds then emit after 3 seconds:

```
Observable.just(1, 2, 3) 
  .concatMap(n -> Observable.timer(n, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) 
  .doOnNext(System.out::println) 
  .toBlocking().subscribe();
```

Comment: I strongly suspect that the OP wanted a variable amount of time, and not a series of constants.